# Typography of letters in circuit symbols

Tags: typography, circuits

How should the letters in circuit symbols look like / be typeset, especially the symbols for voltmeter, amperemeter, generator and motor. Should the V, A, G and M be typeset in the surrounding font (possibly with serifs), in the sourrounding sans-serif font or in a fixed (probably stylized and sans-serif) font regardless of surround fonts?

Comment: They should be in sans-serif.

Comment: @morbusg But in a fixed sans-serif font or the normal sans-serif font surrounding the graphic?

Comment: I don't think it matters; either one.

Comment: I've been trying to find an online reference for my claim for the past hour or so, but haven't been able to find one. So it might just be a memory from my school or school book, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no indication in the standards of the [International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC)](http://www.iec.ch/), or in similar ones from IEEE, about the font family that has to be used in electrical symbols.

What is required is to follow the style rules of the [International System of Units](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/).

Thus, for example, the "V" in the voltmeter symbol represents the unit *volt*, and it should be typeset in an upright shape (not `$V$`), but the font family can be that of the surrounding text.

Comment: I posted the same question in the electrical engineering branch of stackexchange and there the answer was to use a DIN standard font (DIN being the German standardising institution and their standards).